# Precise Focal Length of a Concave Mirror

Tags: visible-light

I have recently been working with concave mirrors, I was unable to understand why the focal length could be half the radius and later found out that it is only accurate for small apertures and angles of incidence. Curious to know more, I created this Concave mirror simulator on Desmos: [ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k60kpstljs?lang=en ]. In the process I found a formula for the actual focal length of a given ray parallel to the principal axis. However this length is dependent on the incident angle and is provided in the Desmos graph above.

Can Somebody please validate this and correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to distinguish rigorous and approximate stigmatism. If there were rigorous stigmatism, the focal point would be the concurrence point of the reflection of incident parallel rays. However, in the case of a spherical mirror, you don't have rigorous stigmatism, i.e. the reflected rays are not concurrent. You'd therefore think that there is no focal point.

The usual surrogate is [paraxial approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraxial_approximation). If you look at the reflected rays, you'll notice that they have a well defined envelope (a [caustic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_(optics))), which in your case is the arc of a nephroid. It has a cusp, which is what you define as the focal point. Doing the math, the distance between the focal length and the vertex point (your $P$) is the focal length:
$$
f = \frac{R}{2}
$$
You can check this with GeoGebra for example, where you can leave the trace of reflected rays as you vary incoming ray. You can kind of see it in your Desmos simulator. As the incident ray gets closer to the optical axis, the point of intersection of the reflected ray with the axis converges to the cusp $F$ with the correct focal length (note that at coincidence, the intersection point is not well defined, which is why the limit process is necessary). Intuitively, in the paraxial approximation, i.e. close to the optical axis, you have concurrence of reflected rays at leading order.

Hope this helps.